# Выдает такую ошибку: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я только начал изучать программирование и вот тут такая проблема, начал решать задачи в acmp, вроде все идет норм но когда хочу посмотреть как это работает не в сайте, а в самом IDLE то ничего не выходить кроме этой проблемы:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
сам код:

```
fin  = open("input.txt")
fout = open("output.txt","w")

a,b = map(int, fin.readline().split())
fout.write(str(a+b))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

хз почему не работает. В файле Input.txt находить 4 и 5. Помогите школьнику

Comment: Для начала сделайте `print(fin.readline().split())`, что напечатает?

Comment: Аянат, у вас в файле input.txt должно быть два числа. Когда вы запускаете программу, то программа не находит эти числа и говорит вам: не хватает значений ( ожидаю 2 числа, а нашла 0 )

Comment: "print(fin.readline().split())" вышли те цифры которые я написал в Input.txt, то есть ['3', '4']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a,b = map(int, fin.readline().split())
```

зависит от того, что содержится в строке, которая извлекается чрез `fin.readline()`

например, если в строке только 1 число или вообще нет чисел, тогда будет ошибка, потому что ничего не может быть записано в переменную `b` или в обе переменные `a, b` соответственно

```
a, b = map(int, "".split()) # ошибка ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
a, b = map(int, "10".split()) # ошибка ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
a, b = map(int, "10 20".split()) # OK, все корректно
a, b = map(int, "10 20 30".split()) # ошибка ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

как выход - лучше считывать информацию в список и потом уже работать с ней в зависимости от размера списка

```
data = list(int, fin.readline().split())
```

Comment: тогда как нужна написать код? Че та я не понял

Comment: ну например если `len(data) != 2`, то вы как-то иначе обрабатываете ситуацию, например не выполняете `data[0] + data[1]`. Проверьте что у вас считывается из файла

Comment: так я додик, только щас осмыслил то что вы написал, но по каким-то причинам мой код начал работать(я хз почему и как). Но то что вы написали я понял, но у меня такая проблема: TypeError: list expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Answer (score 0):

> короче люди я бебра

у меня этот код просто так начал работать, хотя я его не менял ничего, и вот работает, но все равно спасибо @Zhihar, благодаря ему я узнал что такое лист в питоне и я его изучил и написал код который немного был написан как говорил Zhirar.
code:

```
fin  = open("input.txt")
fout = open("output.txt","w")

data = fin.readline()## Заголовок ##
fout.write(str(int(data.split()[0]) + int(data.split()[1])))
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

`